# Inserting pandas dataframe with float values into Oracle

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I can insert normal values like integer, string into Oracle from pandas data frame but when I try float type values , sqlalchemy gives below errors

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Oracle FLOAT types use 'binary precision', which does not convert cleanly from decimal 'precision'.  Please specify this type with a separate Oracle variant, such as Float(precision=53).with_variant(oracle.FLOAT(binary_precision=176), 'oracle'), so that the Oracle specific 'binary_precision' may be specified accurately.
```

here is the complete source code

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy.dialects import oracle


oracle_db = sa.create_engine('oracle://username:password@instance/?service_name=MBCDFE')
conn = oracle_db.connect()
df = pd.DataFrame({
    #"column1": [1, 1, 1], #- inserting into DB works with just numbers
    "column1": [1.2, 1.2, 1.2],
    "column2": ["a", "bb", "c"],
    "column3": ["K", "L", "M"]
})

df.to_sql("python", conn, if_exists="replace", index=True)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

any help will be really appreciated. many thanks.

Comment: Check the bottom of the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html). They reference `sqlalchemy.types` and how to specify the dtype of your columns. You can find more info on `sqlalchemy.types.Float` [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Float).

Comment: @IanThompson - Thank you very much, absolutely the right solution. But, not sure how easy to put this configuration when a Dataframe with more than 100 columns with different types of columns. We can still do but it would have been easier if to_sql() were accepting  some kind of mapping  from PD column datatypes to Oracle types instead of specifying type for each column explicitly.
anyway thank you again.

Comment: You could see what your current datatypes are with `df.dtypes.unique()` and see which need to be mapped to Oracle types. Once you have the map you loop over your `df.dtypes` series and `map` your mapped Oracle types to the columns. I don't have an Oracle connection so can't really test.

Answer (score 1):

You should import [Oracle Data Types](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/oracle.html#oracle-data-types), and use it in `dtype` parameter.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle import (
                                        FLOAT,
                                        NUMBER,
                                        VARCHAR2
                                        )

oracle_db = sa.create_engine('oracle://username:password@instance/?service_name=MBCDFE')
conn = oracle_db.connect()

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "column1": [1.2, 1.2, 1.2],
    "column2": [1235, 1236, 1237],
    "column3": ["K", "L", "M"]
})

dtype = {"column1" : FLOAT(53),
         "column2" : NUMBER,
         "column3": VARCHAR2(20)
        }

df.to_sql("python", conn, if_exists="replace", index=True, dtype=dtype)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score -2):

For Oracle to understand that a number is in float format, you need to convert it to text format and replace the point with a comma. And in a table in Oracle with the format NUMBER it will be added well.

To modify your numbers you can do:

```
df["column1"] = df["column1"].astype(str).str.replace('.', ',')
```

This method will have to be done for each column separately if you have several columns with float data.

Comment: Can you cite documentation on this solution? How would this work for locales like U.S. that use periods instead of commas for decimal digits?

Answer (score -2):

The error you are encountering arises from a discrepancy in handling data types between Pandas and Oracle when using SQLAlchemy. Oracle uses "binary precision" for the FLOAT type, which is not directly compatible with the decimal precision used in Pandas. Here's how you can resolve this:

Use dtype in to_sql: Specify the appropriate data types for the DataFrame columns when calling the to_sql method. You can use sqlalchemy.types.Float to define the data type with binary precision as required by Oracle.

Here's the modified snippet of your code:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import Float

df.to_sql(
    "python",
    conn,
    if_exists="replace",
    index=True,
    dtype={
        "column1": Float(binary_precision=53),
        # Define other data types for other columns if necessary
    }
)
```

In this case, Float(binary_precision=53) defines the data type for the column1 with binary precision suitable for Oracle.

Data Consistency Check: Ensure that the data in your DataFrame genuinely matches the data types you are defining. In your case, column1 should contain values that can be represented as FLOAT.

Commit the Transaction: You are correctly using conn.commit() to commit the transaction. This is important to ensure the changes are saved in the database.

Resource Management: Using a context manager with for handling connections can be safer to ensure the connection closes even if errors occur.

```
with oracle_db.connect() as conn:
    df.to_sql("python", conn, ...)
    conn.commit()
```

Try incorporating these changes into your code and run it again. This should help resolve the issue with inserting float type data into Oracle through Pandas and SQLAlchemy.

Comment: [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541)